# nexus restlet not downloading index

Tags: restlet, nexus

When I add http://maven.restlet.org as proxy repository to my nexus repository (version 1.9.2.4), nexus is not able to download the remote indexes. 
I see the following error in the nexus log:

> org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.ItemNotFoundException: The remoteURL we
>   requested does not exists on remote server
>   (remoteUrl="http://maven.restlet.org/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.gz

Is this a restlet or a nexus problem? How can I use Restlet with Nexus?
The whole stack-trace is:

> Cannot fetch remote index for repository "restlet" [id=restlet]
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: nexus-maven-repository-index.gz (item
>   not found)
>       at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager$2.retrieve(DefaultIndexerManager.java:1114)
>       at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.loadIndexDirectory(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:191)
>       at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.access$300(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:76)
>       at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater$LuceneIndexAdaptor.setIndexFile(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:642)
>       at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:861)
>       at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:157)
>       at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager.updateRemoteIndex(DefaultIndexerManager.java:1132)
>       at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager.downloadRepositoryIndex(DefaultIndexerManager.java:1017)
>       at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager.reindexRepository(DefaultIndexerManager.java:892)
>       at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager.reindexRepository(DefaultIndexerManager.java:841)
>       at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager.reindexRepository(DefaultIndexerManager.java:815)
>       at org.sonatype.nexus.tasks.ReindexTaskHandlerLegacy.reindexRepository(ReindexTaskHandlerLegacy.java:60)
>       at org.sonatype.nexus.tasks.AbstractIndexerTask.doRun(AbstractIndexerTask.java:72)
>       at org.sonatype.nexus.scheduling.AbstractNexusTask.call(AbstractNexusTask.java:159)
>       at org.sonatype.scheduling.DefaultScheduledTask.call(DefaultScheduledTask.java:437)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.ItemNotFoundException: The remoteURL we
>   requested does not exists on remote server
>   (remoteUrl="http://maven.restlet.org/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.gz")
>       at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.storage.remote.commonshttpclient.CommonsHttpClientRemoteStorage.retrieveItem(CommonsHttpClientRemoteStorage.java:240)
>       at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager$2.retrieve(DefaultIndexerManager.java:1097)
>       ... 21 more

Comment: Happy to add Nexus compatibility to our Restlet repository. Do you have details about this special Nexus index file?

Comment: @JeromeLouvel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349261/how-to-index-a-maven-repo-without-nexus-artifactory-etc

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the remote index to use that repository. You won't be able to use the UI to search for artifacts contained in that repository, but Nexus will be able to access artifacts there when directly asked for them (as in "defined as a dependency in a POM").

EDIT: This question is a duplicate of [Nexus - proxy repositories with no indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037941/nexus-proxy-repositories-with-no-indexes).

Comment: Thanks. Indeed if I add the dependency to my POM it downloads the artifacts.